# Find the second distributional derivative of $\left|\sin(x)\right|$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to find the second distributional derivative of $f(x)=\left|\sin(x)\right|$, defined for $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

I have not got far but I started like this:

Let $\varphi$ be defined in $S(\mathbb R)$, then
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(\varphi) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \,\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \varphi \,\mathrm dx
$$

what to do next?

By the way, where can I find the syntax for doing all the symboles?

Comment: Can you compute the first derivative? You need to find where $\sin(x)$ is positive/negative and use integration by parts. With the same methods you can work on the second derivative. Note that boundary terms vanish becasue $\varphi\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Do you know the chain rule for distributional derivative and the derivative of absolute value map as a distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy for computing distributional derivatives is to compute symbolically/naively first, then confirm my answer using integration by parts.  So, symbolically, the first derivative of $f(x)$ should be (by the chain rule):

$$
f^\prime(x)=\text{sgn}(\sin(x))\cos(x)
$$ Where $\text{sgn}(x)$ is the signum function, defined as: 
$$
\text{sgn}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & x<0\\
0 & x=0\\
1 & x>0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then, using the product rule, we get

$$
f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\text{sgn}^\prime(\sin(x))\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)\text{sgn}(\sin(x))
$$ Recall that the derivative of the signum function is $\text{sgn}^\prime(x)=2\delta(x)$, so $\text{sgn}^\prime(\sin(x))\cos^2(x)=2\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}}2\delta(x-k\pi)$.  This is because when $\sin(x)=0$, $\cos^2(x)=1$.  Also note that $\sin(x)\text{sgn}(\sin(x))$ will be exactly $\vert \sin(x)\vert$, since $\text{sgn}(\sin(x))=-1$ when $\sin(x)<0$ and $\text{sgn}(\sin(x))=1$ when $\sin(x)>0$.   Hence we have

$$
f^{\prime\prime}(x)=2\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}}\delta(x-k\pi)-\vert\sin(x)\vert
$$

From here, you should be able to verify this using integration by parts.  The goal is to show that for every $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}$, we have

$$
\langle f^{\prime\prime},\varphi\rangle=\langle f,\varphi^{\prime\prime}\rangle
$$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product.

Comment: How do you define H? when calculating the first derivative I get the same result as TZakrevskiy below, maybe that is the def.

Comment: @Ingvar See edit - it's the same as TZakrevskiy's answer.

Comment: Is this an equvivalent way of defining H(sin(x))?
2*chi_A-1 whera chi is the charactiristic function over A witch consists of those x s.t: 2k*pi<x<2k*pi+pi

Comment: If it is so then when taking the second derivative I dont get a cos^2(x)

Comment: @Ingvar sure, that would be equivalent.  You won't get a $\cos^2(x)$ doing it that way, but we'll end up with the same answer in the end.

Comment: but then you get plus sign in front of the sum if x=2*pi*k and minus sign if x=2*pi*k+pi, the cosine changes the sign?

Comment: @Ingvar sorry, I was mistakenly using the Heaviside function where I should have been using the signum function.  Take a look at the graph of $f^\prime$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sign%28sin%28x%29%29*cos%28x%29) and you'll see why all the delta functions must have a plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

Let's apply the jump formula for derivation of distributions. $|\sin x|$ is continuous and piecewise $C^1$, we write
$$
\left|\sin x\right|'=\begin{cases}\cos x,&x\in [2\pi k,\pi+2\pi k),\\-\cos x,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, this function is no longer continuous, but still piecewise $C^1$, so we will get $\delta$-functions in the second derivative. The jumps are all equal to $2$ and they occur in points of the form $\pi\mathbb Z$.

We can write it as
$$
\left|\sin x\right|''=g+2\sum_{k\in\pi\mathbb Z}\delta_k,
$$
where
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}-\sin x,&x\in [2\pi k,\pi+2\pi k),\\\sin x,&\text{otherwise},\end{cases}=-\left|\sin x\right|,
$$
That is,
$$
\left|\sin x\right|''=-\left|\sin x\right|+2\sum_{k\in\pi\mathbb Z}\delta_k.
$$

Comment: I follow you in calculating the first derivative, but how do you do to state the second one? how to see that we will have a delta function?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to answer an old question. I am doing this question now. Thanks to @md2perpe and @LL3.14 for their useful comments.

---

My definitions: If $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb R)$ then the distribution corresponding to $f$ is defined by $$T_f(\varphi)=\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$$

And derivative of distribution $T_f'(\varphi):=-T_f(\varphi')$.

---

Now let's start: Clearly, $|\sin(x)|$ is locally integrable so $T_{|\sin(x)|}$ can be defined.

$$\begin{align}T_{|\sin(x)|}'(\varphi)&=-T_{|\sin(x)|}(\varphi')\\&=-\int_{\Bbb R}|\sin(x)|\varphi'(x)\,dx\\&=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[-\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\sin(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx+\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\sin(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx\right]\\&=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\cos(x)\varphi(x)\,dx-\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\cos(x)\varphi(x)\,dx\right]\end{align}$$

The sums are finite because $\varphi(x)$ has compact support. In the last step, we applied IBP. Since $\sin(k\pi)=0$ so there are no boundary terms.

$$\begin{align}T_{|\sin(x)|}''(\varphi)&=-T_{|\sin(x)|}'(\varphi')\\&=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[-\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\cos(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx+\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\cos(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx\right]\\&=I+\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[-\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\sin(x)\varphi(x)\,dx+\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\sin(x)\varphi(x)\,dx\right]\\&=I+T_{|\sin(x)|}(\varphi)\end{align}$$

Where, $I$ is the sum of boundary terms. Using $\cos(2n\pi)=1$ and $\cos((2n+1)\pi)=-1$, we can write
$$\begin{align}I&=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[-\cos(x)\varphi(x)\big|_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}+\cos(x)\varphi(x)\big|_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}\right]\\&=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[2\varphi((2k+1)\pi)+\varphi(2k\pi)+\varphi((2k+2)\pi)\right]\end{align}$$

If I write in terms of delta functions, then it is $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[2\delta_{(2k+1)\pi}+\delta_{2k\pi}+\delta_{((2k+2)\pi)}\right](\varphi)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}2\left[\delta_{(2k+1)\pi}+\delta_{2k\pi}\right](\varphi)$.

So the final answer is:$$T_{|\sin(x)|}''(\varphi)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}2\left[\delta_{(2k+1)\pi}+\delta_{2k\pi}\right](\varphi)+T_{|\sin(x)|}(\varphi).$$

Comment: The downvote is probably given because this isn't an answer but rather a question.

Comment: When you consider the expression for $\varphi$ having support $[2\pi-\varepsilon, 4\pi+\varepsilon]$ remember that you have a sum over $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$ So the term $\varphi(2k\pi)$ will apply for both $k=1$ and at $k=2$, and the term $\varphi((2k+2)\pi)$ will apply for both $k=0$ and $k=1.$

Comment: @md2perpe, This is a proper answer and different approach from others. I just made an additional question. Anyway, thank you for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: Before your edit it was rather a question than an answer.

Comment: You have misplaced the last $\pi$ in your last expression. Also, because of the sum over $\mathbb Z$ you can merge the terms $\delta(2k\pi)$ and $\delta((2k+2)\pi)$ into $2\delta(2k\pi).$

Comment: What you have now can be simplified even more. But isn't there an $x$ missing? Shouldn't it be for example $\delta(x-2k\pi)$?

Comment: I am deleting some comments to reduce the number of comments (so that we can talk freely). In my notations $\delta(2k\pi)(\varphi)=\varphi(2k\pi)$ .($\delta(2k\pi)$ is a distribution). What is the meaning of your $\delta(x-2k\pi)$? @md2perpe

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your notation. I'm used to a more function-like notation with $\delta_a(x)$ or $\delta(x-a)$ for a unit mass at $a$.

Comment: @LL3.14 I've changed it accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @md2perpe, I couldn't thank you properly at that time. Thank you very much.

Comment: So now your answer gives the same result as the others, right ? Perhaps you could then edit the initial sentence, and write the full result in an equation?

Comment: $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}2\left[\delta_{(2k+1)\pi}+\delta_{2k\pi}\right](\varphi)$ can be simplified to $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}2\delta_{k\pi}(\varphi)$.